# Java: Build logical expressions and then validate them

Tags: java, boolean

I have a little functionality where I need to determine whether a rule that a user is creating is syntactically valid.

That being said the structure of what I'm building are like the following:

- 1 == 1
- 1 + 1 == 1
- 1 + 1 == 1 OR 1 == 1
- More combinations of the above examples

These expressions are saved in a string variable, e.g:

```
String expression = "";

while(items.hasNext())
{
    String currentItem = items.next();
    expression += currentItem.value();
}

//Check if the expression is valid
```

**VALID EXPRESSIONS**

Valid expressions are the ones that have a logic operator (<, <=, ==, =>, >) and the output would be true or false (doesn't matter which)

- 1 == 1
- 1 < 2
- 1 == 1 OR 1 < 4
- 4 == 9 OR 9 == 3

**INVALID EXPRESSIONS**

Invalid expressions are the ones that doesn't have the proper structure in order to determine whether that expression is true or false.

- 1
- 1+1
- 1===
- ==1
- 1
- 11 (that is number then number)

**NOTE**

I've tried using

> Boolean.valueOf(String)
>
> Boolean.parse(String)
>
> Other types of Boolean methods

Comment: `new javax.script.ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("js").eval("yourString");` Note that it would not throw any exception for expression such as 1+1, but you could then verify that the result is a boolean.

Comment: Boolean.parse expects something like "true" or "false". You need something to do interpreting.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard That's a neat idea, but the script result would also return true/false for any boolean expression. You would also need to check that all tokens are valid tokens AND the result is boolean.

Comment: Ah that's true, I'm tired, sorry.

Comment: By the way, you should use a StringBuilder when concatening string in a loop.

Comment: You could/should use a library like JEval or Commons Math for parsing these expressions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT**   Will now not allow any expression to be success.

**EDIT2**   Examples of what evaluates.

```
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.*;

public class HelloWorld{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");

        String expression = "1+2";   // evaluates to Failure: 3
        String expression = "1+a";   // evaluates to Failure:
        String expression = "1==1";  // evaluates to Success: true
        String expression = "1==2";  // evaluates to Failure: false
        try
        {
            Object result = engine.eval(expression);

            if(result instanceof Boolean)
            {
                System.out.print("Success: ");
                System.out.println(result);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.print("Failure: ");
                System.out.println(result);
            }
        }
        catch(ScriptException e)
        {
            // handle
            System.out.println("Failure");
        }
    }
}
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngineManager.html

Comment: This would return success for all valid JS expressions, which is not what the OP wants.

Comment: @Andrew Eisenberg yes, Indeed. It'll return true or false for all valid JS expressions.

Comment: This is still not correct, for example expression such as `"\"hi\".equals(\"hi\")"` would return true, but is not valid.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard This is true, but if the OP knows that the input will only be integers and comparison operators, then this is a non-issue. I concede that this is not a perfectly robust solution, but it is one that may be able to meet the OP's requirements, as it correctly evaluates their example input.

Comment: `"(1|1)==1"` would return true, is invalid and is integer comparison.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard yes you are totally right- How can I determine this expression is not valid?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard But is this not true: "(one or one) is equal to one"