# JDeveloper ADF: Refresh View Object Rows from DB

Tags: java, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

**BACKGROUND INFORMATION**

Picture this:

I have a functionality where a user defines a rule. A rule is composed by many items. An Item can be:

- Number
- Operator (<, <=, ==, =>, >)
- Operation (+ - / *)

The most easy example of a valid rule would be

> 1 == 1

In order to determine whether the rule is valid I have a little function that builds the expression in which I got help here:

[Java: Build logical expressions and then validate them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38130372/java-build-logical-expressions-and-then-validate-them)

**THE REAL POINT BELOW HERE**

1. User creates a valid rule composed by three items (Commit is made here)
2. User edits the valid and makes it invalid by adding one more item (4TH ITEM)

How can I refresh from the database in order to show only the three items that are actually stored. Since the last one made the rule invalid and therefore a commit WAS NOT MADE.

**Things I've tried**

```
VO.executeQuery();
VO.executeEmptyRowSet();
```

I've read some posts about having a transient attribute and with this determine whether the row is new, modified, etc. I personally don't like this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try dragging the VO's executeQuery operation from the data control panel to your page and dropping it as a button. You can then double click the button so it will create the code in a managed bean.

Comment: VO's executeQuery check whether changed were made DB VRS View Layer. In this case it won't go to the database but rather get all rows from the view layer